# How can I fix the Unity compiler error in version 2019?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

My unity game engine has this problem
.How can I fix this problem. It is very necessary

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.9.1.65535 (9d34608e)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

> error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been
>   imported:
>   'C:\Users\Graphend\Documents\TestUnity\Assets\Plugins\System.Web.dll'
>   and 'C:\Program
>   Files\Unity\Editor\Data\NetStandard\compat\2.0.0\shims\netfx\System.Web.dll'.
>   Remove one of the duplicate references.

Comment: Hello, maybe try to do what the error message tells you, i.e. remove on of the two `System.Web.dll` file.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the one in Graphend\Documents\TestUnity\ but before removing save it somewhere, so that u might turn it back